# SQL: Select rows that contains at least two items and one other item

Tags: sql

I need to verify that a list of information given to me contains the information that has at least two items - engine (starts with either 'E' or 'PE') -  and one another item - chief unit (starts with 'BC').

My initial query was this and I need help modifying it to show me the correct data.

```
select distinct IncidentNum, Unit
from unit
where (unit like 'E%' 
 or unit like 'PE%'
 or unit like 'BC%')
 and unit not like 'EMS%'
and IncidentNum = '19-00001912'
group by incidentnum, unit
having count(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to find the `incidentnum`s that match the conditions:

```
select IncidentNum
from unit
group by IncidentNum
having sum(case when unit like 'E%' or unit like 'PE%' then 1 else 0 end) >= 2 and  -- meets P/E condition
       sum(case when unit like 'BC%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and                    -- meets BC condition
```

You can modify the `having` clause to get the inverse -- the ones that don't match both conditions (`= 0 or = 0`).

I do not know what these conditions are for:

- `unit not like 'EMS%'`
- `IncidentNum = '19-00001912'`

Because they are not part of your question.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question. The engine unit which I need to have at least 2 starts with "E' or "PE". And it looks like the query is just looking for any data that has the unit that starts with "E" or "PE". Is it looking for incidentnum that has at least 2 such units?

Comment: @KenshinH . . . The `HAVING` condition just needs to be adjusted.